# Using css with background image for anchor AND keep text?

Tags: css

I always use the technique of making css buttons with a text-indent of -9999px to hide the text. But what if I want to show the text as well?

I want to place the text at the bottom of a large image I am using. I can only get the text to display at the top.. Anything I can do?

basic code:

```
    .package_EN { background:url(../img/package.png) no-repeat -400px 0px; width:400px; height:293px; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; display:block; color:#fff; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  float:left; }
.package_EN:hover { background:url(../img/package.png) no-repeat -400px -301px; width:400px; height:374px; display:block; }

 <div style="margin-top:120px; margin-left:90px; text-align:center;">
<a class="package_FR" href="img/sponsor_package_en.pdf">Cliquez ici pour télécharger</a>
<a class="package_EN" href="img/sponsor_package_fr.pdf">Click to download</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's on solution, i changed your bg positioning and the color of the text so you can see it
http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/RrC4e/

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a background image and have it above (higher on y axis) your text?

1. Anchor the background image to the top.
2. Set the `padding-top` of the object to the object to the height of the image.
3. Use `display:inline-block` (if you want the padding to not cross into other lines)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HTFvB/ or http://jsfiddle.net/HTFvB/1/

Comment: I am close but I need to position the background since it is part of a larger image and I can't seem to do that while anchoring to top: background:url(../img/package.png) no-repeat top left 0px -400px

Comment: @Sackling In the future, please provide relevant details and requirements in your question. If you need to clip a subsection of a CSS sprite see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770222/css-sprite-techniques-css-background-or-imgs-clip This is a downside to using CSS sprites

Comment: Right. Sorry about that slipped my mind while writing the question. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 0):

Use padding-top on the `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `line-height`. In this case, you'd want to set the line-height to something like `2 * [height of link] - [font-size]`. Using your values:

```
.package_EN { line-height: 574px; } /* (293 * 2) - 12 */
```

Adjust as necessary.

Comment: Or I misunderstand the question, which I thought was about how to get the anchor text to the bottom of the anchor element.

Comment: That seems to push the whole thing down not just the text